# Getting error while calling by class in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am getting a problem while calling a class name by **getElementsClassName** here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Register</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
       <p class="hello" id="hh" onclick="show()">
           Good Knight
       </p>
       
       <script>
           function show(){
               
      let x = document.getElementsByClassName(".hello");
       x.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
           }
       </script>
       
    </body>
</html>
```

Actually I want to print background as a red color. It's not working when I am doing please help me on it.
Thank you

Comment: The `.getElementsByClassName()` method returns a **list** of elements. You have to iterate through the list to affect each element individually.

Comment: Can you give me an example like write a code on it

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` does not require a leading `.`, ie use it as `getElementsByClassName("hello")` See the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: I am also tried this method but it's not working please refer -https://health11.online/register.php for a clarification

Comment: Yaa ok bro thankyou. Problem solved

Comment: You can simply call as getElementsByClassName()[0] index of class names and getElementsByClassName('adding names class name here')